# Can't execute java files on command prompts when they work perfectly in Eclipse IDE, what to do?

Tags: command-line, java

I run the following code in Eclipse IDE:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
    System.out.println("Hello World!" ) ; 
    }
}
```

And it renders the expected output.

When getting into the command prompt (DOS) already in the directory, I type this

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

And then this

```
java HelloWorld
```

And the output reads

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
HelloWorld <wrong name:learning/HelloWorld>
```

With a whole lot more errors, learning being the name of my general package.
What's wrong? I have installed Eclipse x86 SDK 4.2.0 together bit with the latest JRE and JDK both in 64 bit as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld`

My guess is, you ran `java HelloWorld` from within the `learning` directory, right? But the command is expecting the class without any package. Since it's saying `wrong name:learning/HelloWorld`, it means it expects to find the `HelloWorld` class *inside* the `learning` package/directory, *not* in the current one.

Go one directory *up* in the hierarchy (`cd..`), then try running the program with
`java learning.HelloWorld` instead.

Comment: @Darth: `cd` is an internal command. I have been using `cd..` since the DOS days, it works.

Comment: @Karan `cd..` is an alias intended to help people who typo `cd ..` - `cd..` does not work on *nix or OSX systems (unless you go out of your way to add such an alias manually), while `cd ..` is more or less universal-- It works on Linux, OS X, Solaris, Windows' `cmd.exe`, and Windows' Powershell. I would argue it's bad form to suggest people use `cd..` over `cd ..`

Comment: @Darth: I agree about `cd..` working OOTB only in DOS/Win, which is what the OP has. Don't want to argue, but I guess when moving from Windows to a Linux shell this is hardly gonna be the biggest adjustment he'll need to make. Anyway, I don't know one single person who types `cd ..` or `cd \\` in DOS/Win.

Comment: Coming back to your first sentence though (since I'm interested in such historical titbits), do you have any source to show that Tim Paterson (or whoever added this feature) did it simply to help with typos, or was this specifically developed as a feature for the DOS command interpreter/parser to prevent excessive typing (all those spaces add up after all)?

Comment: @Karan I don't have a concrete source currently, and google is being unhelpful on `"cd.." command`. In fact, I'm finding it difficult to find any references to it at all, as everyone seems to document the universal syntax, `cd <dir>`, where `..` means "parent directory". I may have confused myself with other "helpful aliases" that I've found in bash profiles, such as `sl` -> `ls`, and assumed it was added for similar reasons.

Comment: @Darth: Yeah, I've been searching as well. Checked out my old DOS dead-tree manuals, Paterson's 86-DOS manuals, a bunch of sites etc. Might have to ask around some more elsewhere to see if I can dig up more info.